Question about PRML Equation 2.19 on page 73
I am confused about the justification of equation 2.19 in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher M. Bishop. The equation is given below:
$$p(x=1|D) = \int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|D)d\mu = \int_0^1 \mu p(\mu|D)d\mu = E[\mu|D].$$
The justification in the book is given by using the sum and product rule of probability. The sum rule would justify the marginalization of a variable, and the product rule is given by $P(A, B) = P(A|B)P(B)$ or $P(A, B) = P(B|A)P(A)$. This can be extended into $P(AB|C) = P(B|C)P(A|BC)$ or $P(AB|C) = P(A|C)P(B|AC)$.
I can see that we are marginalizing out $\mu$ in the second portion of Equation 2.19. I saw this implying $p(x=1|D) = \int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|D)p(D)d\mu$ because $p(x=1|\mu, D) = p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|D)p(D)d\mu$.
However, the $p(D)$ term is missing. Does anybody have insights here?

Welcome to MSE! Can you please define what $x, \mu, D$ stand or what kind of random variables they are? I think their definition plays a role in the simplification. Also, in general, $p(x = 1|\mu, D) \neq p(x = 1|\mu)p(\mu|D)p(D) \ \mathrm{d}\mu$.

Hi, x is an input that is Bernoulli valued. D is the data random variable the represents the data. $\mu$ is the mean parameter of the data Distribution (I think). $p(x=1| D)$ is supposed to be predictive value of x equaling 1 given the observed data. Also, I must be confused on the equivalence in the last equation. I think I mistook proportionality for equivalence.

The first equality,
$$
p(x=1|D) = \int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu)p(\mu|D)\,d\mu,
$$
is actually a shorthand for the following equality:
$$
p(x=1|D) = \int_0^1 p(x=1|\mu,D)p(\mu|D)\,d\mu,
$$
which in turn follows from the definition of conditional probability densities:
$$
p(x|\mu,D)=\frac{p(x,\mu,D)}{p(\mu,D)},\quad p(\mu|D)=\frac{p(\mu,D)}{p(D)},
$$
where $p(x,\mu,D),p(\mu,D)$ are joint densities. Using these two definitions, we can fill in the gap as follows:
\begin{align*}
p(x|D)&=\int_0^1 p(x,\mu|D)\,d\mu\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{p(x,\mu,D)}{p(D)}\,d\mu\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{p(x,\mu,D)}{p(\mu,D)}\frac{p(\mu,D)}{p(D)}\,d\mu\\
&=\int^1_0p(x|\mu,D)p(\mu|D)\,d\mu.
\end{align*}
The last equality,
$$
\int_0^1 \mu p(\mu|D)\,d\mu = \operatorname{E}[\mu|D],
$$
should be understood as the definition of the conditional density $p(\mu|D)$.
